# How to get part of a URL?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group, regex-greedy

How can I remove all the parts from url except base url and first part. There is no certainty in number of parts. Base url is variable. I tried some regex but in vain.

```php
$url =  http://www.example.com/part1/part2/part3/part4;
base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // Outputs www.example.com

$desired_output = http://www.example.com/part1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we can use a `preg_replace`, with a simple expression, maybe similar to:

```
(.+\.com\/.+?\/).+
```

where we are capturing our desired output using this capturing group:

```
(.+\.com\/.+?\/)
```

and then we swipe to the end of string and replace it with `$1`.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(.+\.com\/.+?\/).+/m';
$str = 'http://www.example.com/part1/part2/part3/part4';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Qonspc/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

For all domains `.com` or not, we might be able to solve it with this expression:

```
(.+\..+?\/.+?\/).+
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(.+\..+?\/.+?\/).+/m';
$str = 'http://www.example.com/part1/part2/part3/part4';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LgR1Ie/1)

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. It works. But my base url is a variable. It may contain .com or .org or any tld. Your answer works only for .com. I have updated my question. Please have a look.